# Only displaying rows in first column (index 0) where cells match a particular date

Tags: c#, datagridview

How would I hide all rows on my dataGridView that do not match the date of "27/11/2013". Currently the code below hides all my rows...

```
private void viewOverdue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CurrencyManager manager = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
    manager.SuspendBinding();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
            if (!string.Equals(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), "27/11/2013", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                row.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                row.Visible = true;
            }
    }
    manager.ResumeBinding();
}
```

Comment: You can use Filter, Take a look at this post It can help you :  [Faster Method to Making DataGridViewRow's non-Visible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663278/faster-method-to-making-datagridviewrows-non-visible)

Comment: Are you sure that `string.Equals(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()` is returning the same format as `"27/11/2013"`?

Comment: @Hanady yep I'm certain

Comment: @Maryam Arshi - how would this look like in the context of my code

Comment: Looks like @Hanady was correct because if all rows are not visible then your cell values never equal the string you are comparing with.  Are you sure its DD/MM/YYYY?

Comment: Yep - would it be worth adding that the datatype in the mdb file is set to DateTime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should parse your `DateTime` to string and then compare.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string d = dt.ToString("dd/M/yyyy");
if (!string.Equals(d, "27/11/2013", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
    row.Visible = false;
}
else
{
    row.Visible = true;
}
```

Also implement the following namespace:

```
using System.Globalization;
```

Comment: thanks for the response. This is what I have done so far: http://pastebin.com/mnYiK5f7. Getting the following error - `The name 'CultureInfo' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Check the updated answer. You have to add the namespace.